# Git - rollback to a previous commit

Tags: git

I committed my work (note *not* pushed) in a known good state. I have since made unwanted local changes (without committing or pushing them). What is the command to undo these changes and revert to my previous commit state?

Please accept my apologies for the beginner question but the suggestions turned up by my googling seem arcane and I would like to be confident in my actions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Pro Git Commnuity book](https://book.git-scm.com/docs/user-manual#fixing-mistakes):

> **Fixing mistakes**
>
> If you've messed up the working tree,
>   but haven't yet committed your
>   mistake, you can return the entire
>   working tree to the last committed
>   state with
>
> `$ git reset --hard HEAD`